# Can I have multiple cameras running on one installed reacTIVision?

Tags: localization, tracking, robotics

I want to introduce another camera into my system for visual tracking of mobile robots using reacTIVision on Ubuntu 16.04.

I went into the camera.xml file of [reacTIVision](http://reactivision.sourceforge.net/), but I could not add another camera and run them at the same time. Do you maybe have a solution for this problem?

Could I install another reacTIVision (maybe different version) on the same laptop and then run both reacTIVisions at the same time?

If anyone has some useful advice or suggestion to try out, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your application scenario you can just start two separate reacTIVision instances. The easiest way would be starting reacTIVision from two different directories, with a separate camera.xml for each of your cameras. Alternatively you can also create two dediciated reacTIVision.xml files each including a separate camera.xml configuration for one of the two cameras. Then start reacTIVIsion with the -c option pointing to that config file.

```
usage: reacTIVision -c [config_file]
the default configuration file is reacTIVision.xml
     -n starts reacTIVision without GUI
     -l lists all available cameras
     -h shows this help message
```